# How to use C# to update a specific row in a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: c#, google-sheets

I want to update column `B` to `1` for the row where the value of column `A` is `2`. In SQL terms, a simple

```
UPDATE SpreadSheet 
SET B = 1
WHERE A = 2
```

Can this be done in a one or two calls to Google Docs without having to loop over rows/columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to use `B` or `A` and couldn't find a way to do the update without looping. This example uses the column header (the value of the first row). Replace `id` and `val` with your own columns.

```
WorksheetFeed wsFeed = spreadsheet.Worksheets;
WorksheetEntry worksheet = (WorksheetEntry)wsFeed.Entries[0];

// Define the URL to request the list feed of the worksheet.
AtomLink listFeedLink = worksheet.Links.FindService(GDataSpreadsheetsNameTable.ListRel, null);

// Fetch the list feed of the worksheet.
ListQuery listQuery = new ListQuery(listFeedLink.HRef.ToString());
listQuery.SpreadsheetQuery = "id = 2";
ListFeed listFeed = service.Query(listQuery);

var row = (ListEntry)listFeed.Entries[0];

foreach (ListEntry.Custom element in row.Elements)
{
    if (element.LocalName == "val")
    {
        element.Value = "1";
    }
}
row.Update();
```

Comment: +1 listFeed.Entries[] collection and row.Elements[] collection are ver useful. This worked for me when i used listFeed.Publish() after row.Update() method (and i suggest others use). It now really works :) thank you very much